# rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work'

Tags: heroku, task, delayed-job

Hi all: I'm on Heroku, installed delayed_job and am getting the above error when I attempt to run a background job. I've tried filing a ticket and scouring the net to no avail.

Thanks...Chris

Answer (score 1):

You only use `rake jobs:work` to start a DJ worker locally. When on Heroku, you have to add workers: `heroku workers +1 --app myapp`. Those cost money though, so you might want to set workers back to 0 when you're done with it.

Edit:

Looks like this is clearly explained in the docs: http://docs.heroku.com/delayed-job#running-dj-workers-on-heroku.

Comment: on heroku, when we start a delayed job, then it automatically calls rake jobs:work, how do I have this rake take not run on heroku?